# Airbnb React Native Maps custom marker with centered text on top

Tags: react-native, maps

[image: screen shot 2016-11-26 at 7 58 48 pm]

When I say React Native Maps I refer to this module: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps

How can I center the text on top of this marker such that it works for any screen size on both ios and android? In the screenshot above the text appears to the top left of the marker. It's a 1.

Code included below. Thanks for any guidance!

```
 <MapView.Marker
  style ={{zIndex: this.state.selectedMarker === marker ? 1 : 0}}
  key={marker.id}
  image={require('../../assets/marker-with-label/marker-with-label.png')}
  coordinate={marker.coordinate}
  >
  <Text>1</Text>
</MapView.Marker>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have done that before. It's basically that what I do when I want to customize a marker:

```
<MapView.Marker  coordinate={marker.latlang}>
  <View style={styles.circle}>
     <Text style={styles.pinText}>{marker.num}</Text>
   </View></MapView.Marker>
```

*Styles*

```
circle: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    borderRadius: 30 / 2,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
},
pinText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 10,
},
```

*Example*

[image: Example marker]

Comment: This only works if you don't zoom. The circle does not shrink if you zoom out using this approach.

Comment: any workarouns to fix that? if we zoomin the marker looks like moving over the map.

Answer (score 2):

This code should help. Worked for me

```
import React from "react";
import { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import Pin from "../assets/Map/Pin.svg";

const CustomMarker = ({ coordinate, pinColor, value }) => {
  return (
    <Marker coordinate={coordinate} pinColor={pinColor}>
      <View
        style={{
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Pin width={45} height={40}></Pin>
       
        <Text
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            color: "white",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            textAlign: "center",
            fontSize: 20,
            marginBottom: 10,
          }}
        >
          {value}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </Marker>
  );
};

export default CustomMarker;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To change the size of the circle whilst zooming in or out, you could adjust it in the onRegionChange and onRegionChangeComplete methods of the MapView, something like this:

```
onRegionChange={({longitudeDelta, latitudeDelta})=>{        
     let markerSize = Math.round(((longitudeDelta + latitudeDelta) / 2) * 2500); 
     this.setState({markerSize});
}}
```

and then use the markersize as the height and width of the marker.

Note: modify the * 2500 to whatever size you need

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you want to add text to your custom marker, try the below updated code :

Pass `handlePin` function to `<Marker>`

```
<MapView
    style={styles.mapStyle}
    region={{
        latitude: this.state.mapLat,
        longitude: this.state.mapLong,
        latitudeDelta: 0.001663,
        longitudeDelta: 0.002001,
            }}
        onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
>
    <Marker
        coordinate={{latitude: 51.5078788, longitude: -0.0877321}}
    >
        {this.handlePin()}
    </Marker>
</MapView>
```

Define the custom marker with `ImageBackground` for marker and `<Text>` and wrap it in a view

```
handlePin = () =>
{
    return (
        <View>
            <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/pin.png')} style={{height: 35, width:35 }}>
                <Text style={{paddingBottom:25}}>Hello</Text>
            </ImageBackground>
        </View>
        )
}
```

[image: custom marker]