# react-native-maps Marker Image prop

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm having a problem setting up the custom images for the Map Markers.

The issue is shown in this snack - https://snack.expo.io/rk1LtHHIz

Uncommenting line 57 shows the issue. It's a simple view with a map and two markers. I tried setting the image prop on the [Marker](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md) - but keep getting the following error:

```
Device: (8:73245) TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0,g.default)(this.props.image)')
```

New to JS and React and can't wrap my head around this one. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Airbnb React Native Maps custom marker with centered text on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822129/airbnb-react-native-maps-custom-marker-with-centered-text-on-top)

Comment: Yea, I looked at that and at tracking issue for custom Markers here - https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/1870 - but haven't been able to figure out if any of the issues are the one I'm encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this does code does in fact work when ran on an actual device. Seems to only be an issue with the snack Expo editor.